# Effecting different component's state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two different components in React "Header" and "Main".

Header:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Logo from './HeaderComps/Logo'
import UserHeader from './HeaderComps/UserHeader'

export default class Header extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <header>
           <Logo />
<UserHeader name ="Boris"/>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

Main:

```
export default class Main extends Component {
state ={isLogged : false}

handleClientFirstImpact = () =>{
if(this.state.isLogged === false){
    return <Switch>
    <Route exact path ='/registration' component={Register} /> 
    <Route exact path ='/login' component={Login} /> 
    </Switch>
}
} 
    render() {
        return (

           <Router>
            <div className="Main">
                {this.handleClientFirstImpact()}

            </div>
            </Router>

        )
    }
}
```

In "Main" I have two components "Register" and "Login".
How do I make Login page effect the Header's state? is there a React technology or a way to do that?
I want the "UserHeader" to show the User name but I don't know how to effect it's parent's state.

Comment: You can keep state in the parent component and pass a function down to handle the state change, I think this will help [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: I suggest you tu use a state container like Redux to store user logged in and leave the components to get user info from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some common component where you will be calling the Main as well as the Header Component. Suppose that component is App Component. 
So inside App you have

```
render() {
  return
     <div>
        <Header />
        <Main />
     </div>
}
```

Now what you can do is keep the userName in this App Component's state and this App Component will pass userName to the  Component as :-

```
 <Header userName={userName} />
```

Also pass a function as a prop to the Main Component which will enable the component to set the State of the Parent Component.

```
<Main setUserName={(newUserName) => this.setState(newUserName)} />
```

now this setUserName prop should be passed on to the components which are called via Route inside the Main Component. Keeping your example in mind (use render prop instead of component for Route):

```
export default class Main extends Component {
state ={isLogged : false}

handleClientFirstImpact = () =>{
const { setUserName } =this.props;
if(this.state.isLogged === false){
    return 
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path ='/registration' 
          render={(props) => <Register {...props} setUserName={setUserName} />}
        /> 
        <Route exact path ='/login' 
          render={(props) => <Login {...props} setUserName={setUserName} />}
        /> 
    </Switch>
  }
} 
    render() {
        return (
           <Router>
            <div className="Main">
                {this.handleClientFirstImpact()}
            </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Now you have passed setUserName as a prop to both login and register and you can use this method to set App component's state which will in turn reflect the changes on the Header component.

Although the solution might work for you. I would advise you to simplify the Application layout. Keep the routing functionality in the main app Component. Use a separate layout component to render similar page layouts. It would avoid confusion in the long run.

Comment: Thank you! would you suggest me to use Redux instead? to make a isLogged?

Comment: It depends on the size and complexity of the application. If the Application grows considerably it would make sense to store this inside of redux. On every page load authentication API would be called which in turn would update the isLoggedIn inside the store and then your App can drive it's state from there.